Steady state solution for 2nd deriviative composite function
I have the following 1-dimensional PDE
$$ \partial_{t}s(t,x)=\partial_{xx}B\left(s(t,x)\right)$$
with initial condition and boundary conditions
$$s(0,x)=s_{0}\\
  s(t,x_{0})=s_{1}\\
  s(t,x_{n})=s_{2}$$
The function $B: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is known.
I am trying to calculate analytically or numerically the steady state solution
$$0=\partial_{xx}B\left(s(t,x)\right)$$
I tried numerically by using a finite difference method for the 2nd deriviative with
$$0=\frac{B_{i+1}-2B_{i}+B_{i-1}}{dx^2}$$
and using a numerical solver to find the root $s$ that solves the equation, but it doesn't converge.
Analytically I tried solving using integration but I haven't been able to.
I got the following by using integration
$$B(s(x))=Cx+D$$
with $C,D\in\mathbb{R}$ but is that correct?
